# How do I change it such that the change is instant?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RandomPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomScreenState createState() => _RandomScreenState();
}

class _RandomScreenState extends State {

  String _selectedValue = 'Select';
  bool appear = false;

  Widget FirstDropDownButton() {
    return Container(
        child: DropdownButton <String> (
          value: _selectedValue,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          underline: Container(
            height: 1.5,
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
          ),
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedValue = newValue;
            });},
          items: <String> ['Select','One'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );}).toList(),
        )
    );
  }

  Widget FirstFlatButton() {
    return FlatButton(
        child: Text("Next"),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_selectedValue == 'Select') {
            print("Cannot be NULL");
            appear = false;
          }
          else if (_selectedValue == 'One')
            appear = true;
        });
  }

  Widget getWidget() {
    if (appear == true) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Hello")
        ],
      );
    }
    else
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Bye")
        ],
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          FirstDropDownButton(),
          FirstFlatButton(),
          getWidget(),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Hi this is a simpler version of the code of mine.

If I choose 'one' from the dropdownbutton the hello text should appear but it doesnt, only when I go ahead and change the value of the dropdownbutton again then will it reflect the change.

How do I make it such that when I select 'one' such that text hello appears immediately and when i select 'select' the text bye appears and hello disappears at the click of the flatbutton without toggling the options again for the change to be reflected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have taken the liberty to modify your code a bit, and made it more general.

For live demo check: [codepen](https://codepen.io/theredcap/pen/JjKEemr)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: RandomPage(),
    ),
  );
}

class RandomPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomScreenState createState() => _RandomScreenState();
}

class _RandomScreenState extends State {
  int _selectedValue = 0;
  bool appear = false;
  List<String> values = ['Select', 'One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  Widget FirstDropDownButton() {
    return Container(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: values[_selectedValue],
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
      underline: Container(
        height: 1.5,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedValue = values.indexWhere((element) => element == newValue);
        });
        changeFlag();
      },
      items: values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ));
  }

  void changeFlag() {
    if (values[_selectedValue] == 'One') {
      setState(() {
        appear = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        appear = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Widget FirstFlatButton() {
    return FlatButton(
        child: Text("Next"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = (_selectedValue + 1) % (values.length);
          });
          changeFlag();
        });
  }

  Widget getWidget() {
    if (appear == true) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text("Hello")],
      );
    } else
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text("Bye")],
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("StackOverflow")),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FirstDropDownButton(),
            FirstFlatButton(),
            getWidget(),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Update: Now that I re-read the question,
I figured that you wanted  to show either the value `Hello` or `Bye` depending upon the value on dropdown, when the user clicked `Next` button,
but i am sure you got the idea whatsoever,
just remove the `setState` on the `flatbutton` and `changeFlag` in the dropdown and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you soo much for ur comments and not leaving me hanging. Still abit new to flutter and rlly needed this help. thanks

Comment: managed to solve it thanks to your comments. thank you for ur code too